# How do I trigger this hover function each time a new image has focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How can I hide all the images in a recordset except the image with the mouse hover on?

Images are displayed from the database and I am trying to manipulate how the images respond when a user hovers on any particular image.

Based on what I have read here on stackoverflow I came up with the following that actually works but with one limitation

On page load it works fine but once you start moving from image to image nothing happens.

I want only the active or image with hover to show while hiding the rest.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.teamDisplay').hover(function(){
    var infoFont = $(".imageDiv")
    var $imgLink = $(this).children(infoFont).attr("data-imgPath");
        $('.memberPicBg').css('background-image', 'url(' + $imgLink + ')');
        $('.teamDisplay').addClass('imageDivOff');
        $(this).addClass('imageDivOn');
    }, function(){
        $('.memberPicBg').css('background-image', 'url(' + $imgLink + ')');
        $('.teamDisplay').addClass('imageDivOn');
        $(this).addClass('imageDivOff');
    });
});
```

I am also using `css` to **show or hide the images** but the hover function appears to work just once on page load.

How do I trigger this hover function each time a new image has focus?

**[This](http://www.weareamplify.com/work/)** is the website with the feature I hope to replicate

UPDATE

The html code

```
    `<div class="memberPicBg">
      <?php do { ?>
        <span class="teamDisplay">
          <?php 
// Show If File Exists (region1)
if (tNG_fileExists("../images/team/", "{members.tmemberphoto}")) {
?>


           <span class="imageDiv" data-imgPath="../images/team/<?php echo $row_members['tmemberphoto']; ?>">
           <span class="teamMemberNameH"><?php echo $row_members['tmember']; ?></span>
            <span class="teamMemberTitleH"><?php echo $row_members['tmemberposition']; ?></span><br /><br />

            <img src="../images/team/<?php echo $row_members['tmemberphoto']; ?>" alt="<?php echo my_meta_description($row_members['tmember'],6); ?>" border="0" />            </span>


            <?php 
// else File Exists (region1)
} else { ?>
            <span class="teamMemberNameH"><?php echo $row_members['tmember']; ?></span>
            <span class="teamMemberTitleH"><?php echo $row_members['tmemberposition']; ?></span>
 <?php } 
// EndIf File Exists (region1)
?>    
 </span>       
            <?php } while ($row_members = mysql_fetch_assoc($members)); ?>
    </div>`
```

NB: apologising if I am not clear enough.

Comment: Make sure that you are adding and removing the existing css class while hover event.

Comment: `$imgLink` is not defined in `mouseout` event

Comment: Add your HTML code.

Comment: FYI: `$imgLink` is only declared in your "handlerIn" callback, thus you can not use it in your "handlerOut" callback.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, He wants to replicate that feature

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses thus far. Much appreciated!

Comment: Problem solved!

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.teamDisplay').hover(function(){
 var infoFont = $(".imageDiv")
 var $imgLink = $(this).children(infoFont).attr("data-imgPath");
        $('.memberPicBg').css('background-image', 'url(' + $imgLink + ')');
  $('.teamDisplay').addClass('imageDivOff');
  $(this).addClass('imageDivOn');
    }, function(){
  $('.teamDisplay').removeClass('imageDivOff');
  $(this).removeClass('imageDivOn');

    });
});`

I removed the classes that I added in the hover (in) in the second function and it's working as intended.

Many thanks.